# Vectorize np.arange or equivalent

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a long 1D array. I'd like to create an array that is the result of `np.arange()` applied to each value in the array plus some constant. E.g if the constant = 3 and my array looks like

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I'd like to get

```
[[1,2,3]
 [2,3,4]
 [3,4,5]
 [4,5,6]
 [5,6,7]]
```

`np.arange()` only accepts scalars as arguments. I played around with `np.vectorize()` a bit to no success. Clearly I could do this with a loop, or with lists and then convert to an array, but I was wondering if there's a good numpy-only solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use addition and broadcasting:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> constant = 3
>>> x[:,None] + np.arange(constant)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

This could also be written as `np.add.outer(x, np.arange(constant))`.